# How to get create geofence by asking people to walk around

Tags: android, android-geofence

We want to create an android app which allows you  to  mark your territory  by opening  the app   and walking around.  Any thoughts on that? How to turn a walking trail into geofence.

Comment: Have you checked this tutorial? 

https://www.raywenderlich.com/7372-geofencing-api-tutorial-for-android

Comment: So you first record the fence. The same as a track logger does. You end up with a polyline in a .gpx file for example. Then you need 'some code' to determine given a lat,lon if that lat,lon is inside or outside of the -closed- polyline. I assume you do not want to use circle geofences as google does.